# VB - Gridview style after index changed

Tags: vb.net, gridview

i've a gridview with pagesize=10, when i load the page and bind grid i've the correct style applied (checkbox cheched or no), but when i go to second page i can't apply the style (checkbox always not checked) and if i came back to the first page i haven't the correst style applied.
At the page load i store all checkbox states into a dictonary to check when i bind the grid.

```
Public listaCheckbox As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Boolean)
```

I tried to apply a style to the first row to understand where I'm wrong but it's always the same thing.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        RecuperaCheckbox() 'to store all checkbox value into listaCheckbox, it works

        If IsPostBack = False Then
            Me.BindGrid2()
        End If

    End Sub
```

```
    Protected Sub OnPageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridViewListaEsp.PageIndexChanging
        GridViewListaEsp.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
        Me.BindGrid2()
    End Sub
```

```
Private Sub BindGrid2()
        
        Query = "SELECT ... 
                    FROM ...;"

        List.SelectCommand = Query

        GridViewListaEsp.DataBind()

        For i = 0 To GridViewListaEsp.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim chk As CheckBox = GridViewListaEsp.Rows(i).FindControl("chkOnOff")
            Dim id_azienda As String = GridViewListaEsp.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text
            listaCheckbox.TryGetValue(id_azienda, chk.Checked) 'works only at the first page load

        Next

        GridViewListaEsp.Rows(0).Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:aqua") 'works only at the first page load

    End Sub
```

Comment: try ading the RecuperaCheckbox() to OnPageIndexChanging or saving listaCheckbox into session and retrieve it before calling BindGrid2

Comment: RecuperaCheckbox() is executed at every page load in fact it contains records when i call BindGrid2. If i put it into "IsPostBack = False" block, i have error on BindGrid2 on indexchange

Comment: Put a stop point and debug the values of listaCheckbox  in OnPageIndexChanging

Comment: I tried to put RecuperaCheckbox() into OnPageIndexChanging but it's the same. listaCheckbox is working but to avoid this issue, i added this line "GridViewListaEsp.Rows(0).Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:aqua")" that should add a style colour at the first row but works only at the first page load

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
to bind grid i used the command:

```
        list.SelectCommand = Query
```

this was working for all thing except for the application of the style after index changing.
I changed part of code with this:

```
        cmdExist = New SACommand(szPrintf(Query), con)
        drExist = cmdExist.ExecuteReader
        Dim DT As New DataTable
        DT.Load(drExist)

        GridViewListaEsp.DataSource = DT
        GridViewListaEsp.DataBind()
```

And now i can apply new style after change index page!